# Actionbar with Fragment tabs and AdMob

Tags: android, admob, android-actionbar

I have an app that uses the ActionBar with tabs in combination with Fragments.
Now I would like to separate the screen into the normal screen at the top, and a small bar at the bottom for the ads:
[image]
Left is the normal screen, the tabs and their Fragments take up the whole screen.
What I want is the situation on the right. The tabs and Fragments take up the red part, the green part is for ads.
So the red part should make room for the ads, I don't want to overlay the ads.

As the Activity which sets up the ActionBar and tabs has no layout, I'm not able to add the AdView.

How can I do this?

**Edit**
This is how I implemented my app. The actionbar with tabs takes care of showing the fragments, so no xml layout file is used in the main Activity.

My code:
`TestActivity.java`

```
public class TestActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupTabs(savedInstanceState);

        initAds();
    }

    private void setupTabs(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        addTab1();
        addTab2();
    }

    private void addTab1() {
        Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setTag("1");
        String tabText = "1";
        tab1.setText(tabText);
        tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragment>(TestActivity.this, "1", MyFragment.class));

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    }

    private void addTab2() {
        Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setTag("2");
        String tabText = "2";
        tab1.setText(tabText);
        tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyFragment>(TestActivity.this, "2", MyFragment.class));

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
    }

    private void initAds(){
        //Here I want to display the ad, only loading once, Just like Davek804 said
    }
}
```

`TabListener.java`

```
public class TabListener<T extends SherlockFragment> implements com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener {
    private final SherlockFragmentActivity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    public TabListener(SherlockFragmentActivity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (preInitializedFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            SherlockFragment mFragment = (SherlockFragment) SherlockFragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            ft.attach(preInitializedFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        SherlockFragment preInitializedFragment = (SherlockFragment) mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(mTag);

        if (preInitializedFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(preInitializedFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

`MyFragment.java`

```
public class MyFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

Comment: So you want the AdView to be visible regardless of which tab the user is on? Basically, and this is incorrect, but what you kind of want, is for the adView to be essentially the entire main layout but for it to occupy only the bottom? So as the user switches tabs, red changes, but green stays constant (NOT a new version of green on each tab)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an XML file containing the AdView definition and use `<include>` to include it at the bottom of each of your fragments.

Alternatively create a layout and your tabs to it. Cf. the reference dos:

> To get started, your layout must include a ViewGroup in which you
>   place each Fragment associated with a tab. Be sure the ViewGroup has a
>   resource ID so you can reference it from your tab-swapping code.
>   Alternatively, if the tab content will fill the activity layout
>   (excluding the action bar), then your activity doesn't need a layout
>   at all (you don't even need to call setContentView()). Instead, you
>   can place each fragment in the default root ViewGroup, which you can
>   refer to with the android.R.id.content ID (you can see this ID used in
>   the sample code below, during fragment transactions).

Comment: That would cause the ad to reload on switching between tabs, and that's not what I want.

Comment: You might want to say so in the question. Then simply create a  RelativeLayout and anchor the AdView to the bottom. Then add your fragments not to `android.R.id.content`, but to a container in your layout (FrameLayout will do). Cf. the reference: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

Answer (score 1):

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/02/android-layout-tricks-2-reusing-layouts.html

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/03/android-layout-tricks-3-optimize-by.html

The second link details how to do things like this picture: [image]