# How to place AdMob at the top of the screen (above) Android Actionbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, admob

I trying to place an AdMob ad at the top of the screen (above) the Android Actionbar.
[image: ActionBar AdMob above]

- yellow = ActionBar
- red = content
- green = AdMob

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10947053/actionbar-with-fragment-tabs-and-admob) I found is to place an ad at the bottom of a screen with Actionbar showing up. But so far I couldn't figure out how to place it at the top of the screen.

I tried it this way:

```
private AdView adView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // main view setup
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // actionbar setup
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setTitle("Search");
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    final LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) findViewById(android.R.id.content).getParent();

    // Create the adView
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "ID");

    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"

    // Add the adView to it
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams parm = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) content.getLayoutParams();
    parm.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
    content.addView(adView);

    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
    adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Below you can see a part of the hierarchy viewer of my app. The view "id/main" is my main layout.
As you can see on the picture the ActionBar has a id called "id/action_bar_container". In my code above I managed to access the FrameLayout "content" but I wasn't able to access the action_bar_container view. Because they are on the same hierarchy level (I think) it should be possible to access that ActionBar view somehow.

[image]

But it didn't work:

[image: Without ActionBar displayed]

Any idea how to achieve that or a link how it could work or an official statement that it doesn't work.

Comment: you can't put anything above action bar in landscape mode, i strugged for weeks with it, till i finally gave up, and put my own bar at the top , if you are in portrait - this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002217/actionbarsherlock-landscape-mode

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems your solution only works if you have NavigationMode TABS enabled?
So you didn't find any other solution and created your own title bar and didn't use actionbar at all?

Comment: Yes
I used TabIndicator instead, which is like a normal listview with a viewpager, which was rather easy to implement, but it does not look exactly the same as the actionbar does

Comment: @viperbone hi, do you have a full sample solution code? I had the some issue and try to do this is fragments

Comment: @Gorets No, sorry I can't help you in that case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use`getRootView()` on any view or`getWindow().getDecorView()` to get the`PhoneDecorView`. It has one child - a vertical`LinearLayout`.

Add your layout there as the first child.

Note that this is a bad, bad idea. From a user experience point of view, this is a horrific strike against all Design Guidelines. The action bar **must be** at the top for a multitude of design reasons.

Second, this might break on OEM-themed devices.

Third, what about tablets in landscape, will you really have such a huge bar at the top?

In conclusion, yes, it's possible but it's a horrible idea. Don't do it.

Comment: Be careful! That is right for my Galaxy S3 mini, but on my Galaxy S4 was com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout instead of LinearLayout. Better solution for me was to insert my own LinearLayout between decorView and view for content.

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {
private ActionBar bar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setTheme(R.style.Theme_Sherlock);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    bar = getSupportActionBar();
    LayoutInflater inflater =       (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View customView = (View)inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_view, null); //<-- put your ad instead of this
    bar.setDisplayOptions(
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM,
            ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME
                    | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
    bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    bar.setCustomView(customView, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
}

 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how it could work with built in Android ActionBar?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, once you choose to work with an ActionBar, it is added in a higher level (of the UI hierarchy) than your layout.

Meaning you have no control as to where it is placed, and what is placed above it.

Your layout starts below the action bar and ends at the bottom of the screen.

In my opinion, if you do find a way to do what you want, it will be very patchy.

Comment: Hi dors, thank you for your response. I added a picture of the hierarchy view. Still I think it should be possible to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You say you have the content frame layout reference. can you get its parent view? cast it to LinearLayout then add your view on the first position.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getParent%28%29

Answer (score 0):

This hardly seems worth the bounty, but a previous question answers this:
[Getting admob above actionbarsherlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12255602/getting-admob-above-actionbarsherlock)

The trick is to switch over from using the google actionbar to actionbarsherlock library. This is likely a good idea for your app anyway, as it allows you to support the actionbar on older builds of android.

The user claims to have gotten that to work.