# create scaffold with global container on top

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need a global area on top to show some ads. This are remains the same for all pages and widgets. So far I've got this:

```
Stack(
            children: [
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                          color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          height: bannerHeight,
                          child:  MY_BANNER,
                        ),
                  Expanded(child: child!), // this has to be dynamic
                ],
              ),
            ],
          );
```

What's the problem? It creates an extra padding for the AppBar that I don't know how to remove:

[image]

Comment: try wrapping your stack in a safearea(top: false
child: Stack(rest of code)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken safeare should only be inside body

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a space on top of `AppBar` you can put your banner ads below it. For this you can make a custom `MyAppBar` widget and use this custom widget inside the `Scaffold`.

```
class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;

  MyAppBar(this.title) : preferredSize = const Size.fromHeight(110);

  @override
  final Size preferredSize;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        AppBar(
          title: Text(
            title,
          ),
        ),
        Center(
          child: Container( // Place your ad here
            color: Colors.red,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
            height: 50,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

and use it like

```
Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(
        "Hello App",
      ),
),
```

Comment: sorry but I don't understand your approach. Why I'd like to have an appBar on top and also without any scaffold wrapping it? Those expanded widgets I have are other pages

Comment: The reason why I said to place the banner ad below appbar is that, cause of desgin and admob guidelines, you can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17530640/16907012) and [this](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6128877?hl=en). Also you can use this custom widget same like `AppBar`.

Comment: And if you want to put it in top of it just move the `Conatiner` above

Comment: My ad container respect all those rules. In fact I could get accidental clicks if I place it at the bottom instead. But let think on an empty container, not on ads. If I put it on top I have the same issue: the appbar should be inside a scaffold and this needs to be expanded somehow. Those pages there are dynamic. What at I have is Expanded(child: child!)

Comment: Feel free to update your answer according to my question

Comment: Sure, need some clarity about the answer which you [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71758924/16907012)

Answer (score 0):

```
return Scaffold(
            body: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: MY_BANNER
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Expanded(child: child!),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          );
```

[image]

Comment: Does this solve your problem? I also had a question your other pages are present inside the `Expanded` and not inside another `Scaffold`?

Comment: yeah, it does. The child inside that expanded includes the different pages. All of this is inside the builder in the MaterialApp. Basically I needed to remove the Stack and use another scaffold with its savearea